# Can't find windows service in service lists

Tags: c#, windows-services

I installed a Windows Service under an account type user in service installer. When I try to start it from service lists I can't find it. If I change the account type to local service in the installer then I can find it. I need to built it under a user account. How to solve this?

Comment: If you can't find a service in the Services window, it's because it's not installed, simple as that. It might not install if you have the credentials for the user correct or that user isn't allowed to run services. You can always change the user the service is running as from the Services window.

Answer (score 0):

save this text to a batch file(.bat) and run in the sample folder with your window service

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO ------------------------------ Auto Install Windows Service -----------------------------
ECHO -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO --- Typing the path of Windows Service need to install
@SET /p serviceName=
IF NOT "%serviceName%" == "" (
    ECHO --- Installing "%serviceName%"
    ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil %serviceName% -i
    net start yourservicename
    ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PAUSE
)
```

Comment: I'm worried that he has not used the right method to install window service

Comment: I installed windows service from developer command prompt 2015 installutil servicename.exe

Comment: after you install you need to run the command bellow
------- net start yourservicename

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happen when you install the service and the List Service Window is open. just install the service with the service windows close, sound silly but it works.